# How to set multi-path to export image files with Webpack file-loader

Tags: javascript, image, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm researching Webpack to build my module bundle. I use file-loader to load image files in javascript. These line is used to load image files:

```
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      'image-webpack-loader'
    ]
  }
```

But I have trouble with it. Image path is compiled in css not as expected. My app have structure:

[image: structure]

Images is loaded by **require()** in app/views/index.pug:

```
img(src= require('../images/logo.png'), alt= 'logo')
```

and **background-image: url()** in app/styles/style.css:

```
.test {
  background-image: url('../images/logo.png');
}
```

======
After it is compiled, image path in build/index.html is:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

but image path in build/css/style.css is:

```
.test {
  background-image: url(images/logo.png);
}
```

How can I detect when file-loader is scanning image in html or css? Or any solution to solve this problem?

Thank you.